# CURL Version support on PHP

Tags: php, unix, curl

I am having issues with the twitter API and getting error:

Error: "SSL connect error" - Code: 35

I have seen that this could be an cURL version issue and need to update.

Currently we have version 7.19.7, I believe we need to go to at least 7.42 (latest is 7.65.3)

We have php version 5.6.31, does anyone know if these are supported or if there are any issues upgrading?

Cant find any supported platform info anywhere.

We are using TwitterOAuth:

Config call as follows:

```
function http($url, $method, $postfields = NULL) {
    $this->http_info = array();
    $ci = curl_init();
    /* Curl settings */
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,1);
```

Comment: Have you tried to turn off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` ?

Comment: yea, can you let us see what your curl function looks like?

Comment: Currently PHP won't load newest versions of curl

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and i solved it withe this changes in my Curl call.

- Change CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false
- Change CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false
- Change CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 1, or the version that the server uses.

Anyway, it would be helpful to be able to see the call you're making.

Comment: According to Google, error 35 means unsupported SSL version or protocol. That shouldn't have anything to do with invalid certifcates.

Comment: Yes, i think the key is the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION

Comment: @RaúlPérezLópez I have added information and made the suggested changes but still no joy, still error 35.

Comment: Can't turn if off in this case - contains secret keys.